# Is log of ETS(MNM) a ETS(ANA) model?

Tags: time-series

Given two time series models $ETS(MNM)$ and $ETS(ANA)$. If we replace $y_t $ by $\ln y_t $ in $ETS(MNM)$, is it true the model will become $ETS(ANA)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not exactly the same, however the log transformation makes somewhat $ANA$ model $MNM$. Let's write the equations for the both models.

$$ ETS(MNM) = \begin{cases} y_t = l_{t-1}\cdot s_{t-12}\cdot (1+u_t) \\
 l_t = l_{t-1}\cdot (1+\alpha u_t)\\  s_t = s_{t-12}\cdot (1+\gamma u_t) \end{cases}  $$

$$ ETS(ANA) = \begin{cases} y_t = l_{t-1} + s_{t-12} + u_t \\
 l_t = l_{t-1}+\alpha u_t\\  s_t = s_{t-12} + \gamma u_t \end{cases}  $$
Remember that $\ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b$. Hence,
$$ \ln y_t = \ln(l_{t-1}) + \ln(s_{t-12}) + \ln(1 + u_t)$$
Same for other equations.
As we can see, the models are not exactly the same, however it became additive ($ANA$).